# 3D rotated text in child swf incorrect when loaded in to flex project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, text, 3d

I have a SWF that when played as standalone shows its 3d rotated text correctly.  However, when loaded into a flex built parent SWF, the child SWF's text rotation is off?  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It may help if you define "off".  What makes it off?  How are you loading it?  How are you playing it as a stand alone?  Also show some code.

Comment: I have this problem too. When a SWF is loaded into another SWF, any 3D-rotated text doesn't show up. Seems like a bit of a bug.

Comment: It appears to be Flash Player misreading the 0,0 point on drawing. I have the same issue and not found a solution: setting any 3D property in a loaded SWF causes the content to jump around, between where I want it and approx an extra x,y from that point, on resizing the window or drawing a translucent box over the top of the content.